# PHP замена прозрачного фона в png на белый

Tags: php, изображения, gd

Всем привет, делаю загрузку картинок для превью товаров(в магазине).

Есть такая функция

```html
<?php
  function resize($file, $type = 1, $quality = 75, $tmp_path){
            $max_mini_size = 1000;
            $max_size = 800;

            if ($file['type'] == 'image/jpeg') $src = imagecreatefromjpeg ($file['tmp_name']);
            else if ($file['type'] == 'image/png') $src = imagecreatefrompng ($file['tmp_name']);
            else if ($file['type'] == 'image/gif') $src = imagecreatefromgif ($file['tmp_name']);
            else return false;

            $width_src = imagesx($src); 
            $height_src = imagesy($src);

            if ($type == 1)
                $width = $max_mini_size;
            else if ($type == 2)
                $width = $max_size;

            if ($width_src < $width) {
                $ratio       = $width_src/$width;
                $width_dest  = round($width_src/$ratio);
                $height_dest = round($height_src/$ratio);
 
                $dest = imagecreatetruecolor($width_dest, $height_dest);        

                imagecopyresampled($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width_dest, $height_dest, $width_src, $height_src);

                imagejpeg($src, $tmp_path . $file['name'], $quality);

                imagedestroy($dest);
                imagedestroy($src);
                echo 'no';

                return $file['name'];
            }else {
                imagejpeg($src, $tmp_path . $file['name'], $quality);

                imagedestroy($src);
                
                return $file['name'];
            }
?>
```

она работает нормально, но есть одно но -- если я загружаю png картинку с прозрачным фоном, то этот прозрачный фон заменяется на черный, а мнея нужен белый фон, что я только не перепробовал!

Самое близкое по нужному мне результату это --

```html
<?php
  $white = imagecolorallocate($src, 255, 255, 255);
  imagefill ($src, 0, 0, $white);
>?
```

Но здесь еще одно НО -- оно заливает только те места, которые не замкнуты, те вот такой результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На картинке иконка сохранения с прозрачным фоном,который заменяется на белый, но если что-то "перегараживает" путь, то там остается черный цвет (на картинке выделены такие места красным.

Так же есть функция imagefilledrectangle

Comment: похоже надо перебрать все пиксели, и если пиксель черный и прозрачный, заменить его на белый непрозрачный.

Comment: а не подскажешь, как это реализовать?

Comment: и это наверное будет не производительно? А если черные пиксели будут на самой картинке?

Comment: отчасти похожее есть тут http://forum.php.su/topic.php?forum=71&topic=12278

Comment: а если попробовать как-то сделать padding для картинки? Чтобы не было "перегородок". только как это сделать?

Comment: @ВладРогов как вариант - зафиксировать размер изображения, создать чёрный квадрат через imagepolygon чуть больше изображения(Если знаете параметра чёрного цвета, который хотите заменить, если нет, попробовать определить по пикселям imagecolorat). Затем Вообще понять бы что на этих картинках изначально может быть. Поменять цвет заливкой и обрезать по начальным данным размера изображения.

Comment: делаю сайт на подобие авито, те на картинках просто фото товара